# List in another page flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm new in programming...

I want to renderize the names of the items in the list, inside a dropdown in another page.

```
class Fermentable {
  final String name;
  final String? country;
  final String category;
  final String type;
  final int color;
  final double ppg;

  Fermentable({
    required this.name,
    required this.country,
    required this.category,
    required this.type,
    required this.color,
    required this.ppg,
  });
}

List<Fermentable> fermentables = [
  Fermentable(
    name: "Malt",
    country: 'Germany',
    category: 'Grain',
    type: 'Malt',
    color: 4,
    ppg: 12,
  ),
...
```

How can i do that? I'm having trouble to think a solution

Comment: Pass `fermentables` and use `dropdown`, programming is mostly about thinking  :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your another page

```dart
class MyAnotherPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Fermentable> fermentables;
  const MyAnotherPage({super.key, required this.fermentables});

  @override
  State<MyAnotherPage> createState() => _MyAnotherPageState();
}

class _MyAnotherPageState extends State<MyAnotherPage> {
  Fermentable? selectedItem;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Text("${selectedItem?.name}"),
          DropdownButton<Fermentable?>(
            items: widget.fermentables
                .map(
                  (e) => DropdownMenuItem<Fermentable>(
                    child: Text(e.name),
                  ),
                )
                .toList(),
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                selectedItem = value;
              });
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And while navigating or using this page pass item like

```dart
MyAnotherPage(fermentables: fermentables)
```

Find more about [DropdownButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html)